# Slider current/total before onclick change

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, slider, carousel

It's [foundation zurb 6/orbit slider](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/orbit.html).

How to display count current/total before the `slidechange.zf.orbit` event? Should I add some event before, on window load or something else?

First slide shows without counter, only when click it visible.

```
<div class="orbit" role="region" aria-label="Favorite Space Pictures" data-orbit>
  <ul class="orbit-container">
    <button class="orbit-previous"><span class="show-for-sr">Previous Slide</span><li></li></button>
    <button class="orbit-next"><span class="show-for-sr">Next Slide</span><li></li></button>
    <li class="is-active orbit-slide">
      <img class="orbit-image" src="../images/demo-img/screen-shot.png" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="orbit-slide">
      <img class="orbit-image" src="../images/demo-img/screen-shot.png" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="orbit-slide">
      <img class="orbit-image" src="../images/demo-img/screen-shot.png" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="orbit-slide">
      <img class="orbit-image" src="../images/demo-img/event-demo.png" alt="">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <nav class="orbit-bullets">
    <button class="is-active" data-slide="0"><span class="show-for-sr">First slide details.</span><span class="show-for-sr">Current Slide</span></button>
    <button data-slide="1"><span class="show-for-sr">Second slide details.</span></button>
    <button data-slide="2"><span class="show-for-sr">Third slide details.</span></button>
    <button data-slide="3"><span class="show-for-sr">Fourth slide details.</span></button>
  </nav>
  <div class="slider-number"></div>
</div>

<script>
(function() {
  function slideNumber() {
    var totalItems = $('li.orbit-slide').length;
    var currentItem = $('li.orbit-slide.is-active').index() - 1;
    $('.slider-number').html(currentItem + '/' + totalItems);
  }
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    $('[data-orbit]').on('slidechange.zf.orbit', slideNumber);
  });
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. [The `DOMContentLoaded` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) is just an event you are looking for.

> The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading.

So call the `slideNumber()` function one more time at this event:

```js
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        function slideNumber() {
          var totalItems = $('li.orbit-slide').length;
          var currentItem = $('li.orbit-slide.is-active').index() - 1;
          $('.slider-number').html(currentItem + '/' + totalItems);
        }
        slideNumber();
        $('[data-orbit]').on('slidechange.zf.orbit', slideNumber);
    });
</script>
```

2. Foundation uses jQuery. So you can use [the .ready() method](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) instead of `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded" ...`. It looks like `$(function() {`.
3. Do not force a function to define `totalItems` and `$('.slider-number')`with each new call. Use global variables instead.

```js
<script>
    $(function() {
        var totalItems = $('li.orbit-slide').length;
        var selectNumber = $('.slider-number');
        
        slideNumber();
        $('[data-orbit]').on('slidechange.zf.orbit', slideNumber);
        
        function slideNumber() {
            var currentItem = $('li.orbit-slide.is-active').index() - 1;
            sliderNumber.html(currentItem + '/' + totalItems);
        };
    });
</script>
```

Please check the result: http://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/XjrLZj

[image: screenshot]

```js
$(document).foundation();  // initialize every Foundation plugin

var totalItems = $('li.orbit-slide').length;
var selectNumber = $('.slider-number');

slideNumber();
$('.orbit').on('slidechange.zf.orbit', slideNumber);

function slideNumber() {
  var currentItem = $('li.orbit-slide.is-active').index() - 1;
  selectNumber.text(currentItem + '/' + totalItems);
}
```

```css
.slider-number {
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.3/foundation.min.css">

<div class="orbit" role="region" data-orbit data-timer-delay="3000" data-use-m-u-i="false">
  <ul class="orbit-container">
    <button class="orbit-previous">&#9664;&#xFE0E;</button>
    <button class="orbit-next">&#9654;&#xFE0E;</button>
    <li class="orbit-slide is-active">
      <img class="orbit-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x300/c69/f9c/?text=1" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="orbit-slide">
      <img class="orbit-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x300/9c6/cf9/?text=2" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="orbit-slide">
      <img class="orbit-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x300/69c/9cf/?text=3" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="orbit-slide">
      <img class="orbit-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x300/96c/c9f/?text=4" alt="">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <nav class="orbit-bullets">
    <button data-slide="0" class="is-active"></button>
    <button data-slide="1"></button>
    <button data-slide="2"></button>
    <button data-slide="3"></button>
  </nav>
  <div class="slider-number"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.3/foundation.min.js"></script>
```